# Error 1064 in MySQL trying Forward Engineering

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mariadb, create-table

I'm new to MySQL and when I tried to do the "Forward Engineer" I've encountered this error:

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Vendite_Prodotti`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Prodotti_idProdotti`)
    ' at line 11
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`Vendite`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Vendite` (
          `idVendite` INT NOT NULL,
          `dataVendita` DATETIME NULL,
          `qta` INT NULL,
          `costo` FLOAT NULL,
          `Prodotti_idProdotti` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idVendite`),
          INDEX `fk_Vendite_Prodotti_idx` (`Prodotti_idProdotti` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Vendite_Prodotti`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Prodotti_idProdotti`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Prodotti` (`idProdotti`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I know there are a lot of questions about this topic but I've seen that it's a very specific. Also being new to SQL I have no idea what the problem could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as concerns, MariaDB does not support invisible indexes (only MySQL 8.0 supports that), so the error comes from the use of the `VISIBLE` keyword.

Since indexes are visible by default anyway, I would suggest just removing it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Vendite` (
      `idVendite` INT NOT NULL,
      `dataVendita` DATETIME NULL,
      `qta` INT NULL,
      `costo` FLOAT NULL,
      `Prodotti_idProdotti` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idVendite`),
      INDEX `fk_Vendite_Prodotti_idx` (`Prodotti_idProdotti`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Vendite_Prodotti`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Prodotti_idProdotti`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Prodotti` (`idProdotti`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```